# How to expand the css gradient?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I need help with auto expanding a gradient done in css. Like, if I enter my website with my mobile phone, it auto adjusts to it. Actualy, the website doesn't auto adjust to the browsers very well: it does in my pc with google chrome, but it doesn't in other browsers or devices.

http://jsfiddle.net/g4YNk/

```
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<script language="JavaScript">

<!--
function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
//-->
</script>

<body>

   <div id="wrapper">

         <div id="content">
             <iframe src="http://www.9gag.com" width="800px" height="400px" name="CHANGETHIS" id="CHANGETHIS" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('CHANGETHIS');"></iframe>     
<H1>HOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLAHOLAGOLA</H1>

         </div>

   </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->   
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

html, body {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-height: 100%
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body {
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
        min-height: 100%
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    right bottom,
    color-stop(0.07, #59BFFF),
    color-stop(1, #000000)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right bottom, #59BFFF 7%, #000000 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right bottom, #59BFFF 7%, #000000 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right bottom, #59BFFF 7%, #000000 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right bottom, #59BFFF 7%, #000000 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #59BFFF 7%, #000000 100%);

}

#wrapper { 
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:transparent;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height: 100%;
}
 background-color:Red;
}

#content {
 background: Yellow;
}
```

FIX:

REPLACE PREVIOUS CSS FOR THIS ONE:

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

html, body {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body {
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    right bottom,
    color-stop(0.07, #59BFFF),
    color-stop(1, #000000)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right bottom, #59BFFF 7%, #000000 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right bottom, #59BFFF 7%, #000000 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right bottom, #59BFFF 7%, #000000 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right bottom, #59BFFF 7%, #000000 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #59BFFF 7%, #000000 100%);

}

#wrapper { 
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    width:700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:transparent;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
 background-color:Red;
}

#content {
 background: Yellow;
}

{}{}{}{}{}{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look into css media queries:
you can specify different settings for each screen size (or other media)

for your Iframe, you can just set it to 'width=100%' and it will fill the width of '#content'

eg:

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px){
    #wrapper {
        /*
         * css gradient here
         */
    }
    #content{
        margin:0 auto;
        max-width:300px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:1024px){
    #wrapper {
        /*
         * css gradient here
         */
    }
    #content{
        margin:0 auto;
        max-width:1000px;
    }
}
```

this is a great place to get started:
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

to have a gradient that sits behind the iframe, and fills up the width and height of the 'viewable area' then you would need to do something like this with your markup:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
    <div id="content">
        iframe goes here
    </div>
</body>
```

and alter your css for the #wrapper element and the #content element to be something like:

```
#wrapper {
    background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}
#content{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Here is a proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/aa7vJ/

Comment: the gradient, dont expand verticaly, what can i do? if I put "min-height:1200px" in body, the gradient is about 1200px, but i want it to automaticaly determinate the min height of the current device

Comment: ahh, I think I know what you mean now, ill expand my answer

Answer (score 0):

To make your web site adjust to devices. You will first of all need a viewport meta tag in your documents head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

This will prevent the devices from zooming the content.

Next you will need to specify all css widths in % rather than pixels (you can combine it with a max-width)

```
#mainWrapper{
    width:80%;
    max-width:1200px;
}
```

If you have some elements that will need to be in px you can use mediaqueries to specify different values for different displays.

About the CSS gradients: The gradients will allways take up the entire size of the element you have assigned it to. You might be able to change this by playing around with background-position and background-attachment with css (not really sure on that)

Here's a good CSS gradient generator that will generate code for all browsers:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: the gradient dont expand verticaly